# 1 click then disable - PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I have been looking around on the forum and tried everything but I cant get my button to disable after clicking it, I just started using php and this is one of my first projects. Its a like and dislike system. Does anyone know the awnser?
when you press a like button or dislike button I want both buttons to be disabled.

```
<!--Like System-->
<center>

<?php

$sql = "SELECT * FROM likes";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        ?>  <h1 class="lcount"><?php    echo $row["average"];?> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-signal"></span></h1></br><?php

    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
?>

<?php

$sql = "SELECT * FROM likes";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        ?>  <h1 class="lcount"><?php    echo $row["like"];?> 
        <span style="color: green;"class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span></h1></br>

<?php
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
?>

<?php

$sql = "SELECT * FROM likes";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        ?>  <h1 class="lcount"><?php    echo $row["dislike"];?> 
        <span style="color: red;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"></span></h1>

<?php
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
?>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['like'])){

    $sql = "UPDATE `likes` SET `like` = `like` + 1 , `average` = `average` + 1";


    if (mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
    } else {
        echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($con);
    }
}
?>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['dislike'])){

    $sql = "UPDATE `likes` SET `dislike` = `dislike` + 1 , `average` = `average` - 1";


    if (mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
    } else {
        echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($con);
    }
}
?>

    <form type="#" method="post">
        <button name="like" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span></button>

        <button name="dislike" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"></span></button>
    </form>
</center>
<!--Like System END-->
```

Comment: I feel like javascript would be more suitable for this

Comment: cant it work with only php?

Comment: PHP requires you to reload page, since the code executes on the server. Javascript executes in the browser, so it's more suitable for manipulating UI, for instance, disabling a button. You could, in theory, do that in PHP but it'd probably be very messy and overall not worth it

Comment: it's maybe helpful to read little bit about php and js :-/

Comment: so what code do you prefere for this project? javascript, jquery?

Comment: jQuery is just a library for broswer-side Javascript. As Eugen suggested, consider reading about differences between PHP and Javascript and where should you use which.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If you want to only PHP use like this:**

```
<?php

$status = 'enabled';

if (isset($_POST['like'])) {
    $status = 'disabled';
}


?>

<form type="#" method="post">
    <button name="like" type="submit" class="btn btn-success" <?=$status?>>
                Button is <?=$status?>
    </button>
</form>
```

**You can use Jquery like this:**

https://jsfiddle.net/y4qLew3s/1/

**Updated:**

I updated. It works with like or dislike button:

https://jsfiddle.net/y4qLew3s/3/

Comment: well this worked, but only the button that is clicked will be disabled is there a way to disable the dislike button to?

Comment: The classes of the buttons have to stay the way they are because im using bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

**in javascript**

with `setAttribute()`

```
function disable(){
    document.getElementById('submit').setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
```

}

**updated**
if you disable both button at same time

```
<script>
function disable(){
  document.getElementById('submit').setAttribute("disabled", "disabled"); 
  document.getElementById('submit1').setAttribute("disabled", "disabled"); 
}
</script>

<input title="" id="submit" type="submit" name="button" onclick="disable()" value="like">

<input title="" id="submit1" type="submit" name="button" onclick="disable()" value="unlike">
```

[check here](https://jsfiddle.net/5ufa6yLb/)

Comment: 'submit' is not the id

Comment: @KOUROUMA it's the example.